# Check if something works

Tags: javascript, testing, cross-browser

I'm trying to test what is available on a specific browser (JavaScript-wise).

If I just typed this for example:

```
function checksetAttribute(){
    if(document.getElementById("blar").setAttribute("name","blarDiv")){
        alert("Your browser supports it.");
    }
    else{
        alert("Your browser does not support it.");
    }
}
```

Would this return a true answer as to whether or not the property(ies) work?

Comment: Depends on what you want to test. If you want to test whether the method `setAttribute` exists, then no, it would throw an error if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether a certain property works, not whether `setAttribute` works, then this is the wrong approach, as `setAttribute` always returns `undefined` (== false). Instead, test whether the element has the attribute name as a key - and use a new element instead of one pulled from the DOM, because elements in the DOM could have been modified.

```
function attributeWorks(attr, within) {
    return document.createElement(within || 'div').hasOwnProperty(attr);
}
```

I added the `within` parameter because some properties exist only on certain types of elements: for example, if you always test against a `<div>`, then the function will return `false` for `href`.

If you want to test whether the `setAttribute` function works this is still the wrong approach, because, if `setAttribute` is not implemented, trying to execute it will throw an error instead of returning false. We can use the same method as above, with the simplification that we already know the parameters:

```
function setAttributeWorks() {
    return document.createElement('div').hasOwnProperty('setAttribute');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the code you have there would fail if "setAttribute" was not supported.

```
var a = document.createElement("div");
if(a.setAttribute){
    alert("VERY SUPPORTED");
}else{
    alert("Not supported");
}
```

This would check to see if the setAttribute method is available on dom elements.

Comment: `Object.prototype.setAttribute = 1;`. I promise I won't do it, but I can't speak for the rest of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

No. Assuming the browser supports `document.getElementById` and `setAttribute`, it will just set the name attribute. As that method [returns `void`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) (which is falsy), it will always alert `"Your browser does not support it."` - unless an Exception is thrown.

It neither will check whether the browser supports `name` attributes.